# How to add middleware for /auth/local login in Strapi?

Tags: backend, strapi

I'm trying to add extra validations for **/auth/local** login, is there a way to add a middleware to /api/auth/local route without adding it to global config middleware?

I tried adding it to application level **/config/middlewares**

```js
import { Strapi } from "@strapi/strapi";

export default (config, { strapi }: { strapi: Strapi }) => {
  
  return async (ctx, next) => {
    if (ctx.request.url === "/api/auth/local" && ctx.request.method === 'POST') {
     // Validations

    await next();
    return;
  };
};
```

But I need it to add that middleware just for accessing the builtin login handler

Comment: Can you add more details please? What have you tried? Are using a Framework?

Comment: @YUSOFKHAN I'm using https://strapi.io for the backend api.

Comment: I can see that. But, I mean what else are you using? MERN stack? Or other tech?

Answer (score 0):

Or you may achieve it by policy:

src/extensions/users-permissions/strapi-server.ts:

```
import '@strapi/strapi';
export default (plugin: any) => {
  plugin.routes['content-api'].routes = plugin.routes['content-api'].routes.map((item) => {
    if (item.method == 'POST' && item.path == '/auth/local') {
      item.config.policies = ['global::authPolicy'];
    }
    return item;
  });
  return plugin;
};
```

src/policies/authPolicy.ts:

```
import {Strapi} from '@strapi/strapi';
export default (policyContext, config, {strapi}: {strapi: Strapi}) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(policyContext.request.body));
  return true; // return false
};
```